# SDL_Rect: What is the formula to get a rectangle in the center of the screen?

Tags: sdl

I'm currently trying my hand at SDL and would like to know how to go about getting a rectangle in the center of the screen.

For example, let's say I have a 640x480 screen, and I want a rectangle that is half the width and height of those resolutions to be in the middle of the screen. I know it would be:

`SDL_Rect centerRect = { 640 / 4, 480 / 4, 640 / 2, 480 / 2 };`

Is there a formula that would allow me to put any rectangle of any width and height in the middle each time?

Note: I'm not trying to find the co-ordinates of the center point of the rectangle. Just the co-ordinates for the top left point when all I have to go by is the width and height of the screen and rectangle.

Answer (score 7):

Origin of your screen is top/left. 
Middle of the screen:

```
xcenter = w / 2; ycenter = h/2;
```

Left upper point:

```
x = xcenter - (winrect.width()/2);
y = ycenter - (winrect.height()/2);
```

Now you only have to place your window there.